# javascript array length not displayed in my console log

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm developing an HTML5 canvas game, and I have an array of images which are being drawn to the canvas. The images from the array are currently all  being drawn correctly, and I have a console.log line which I want to use to display the size of the array in the console. But for some reason, the console keeps telling me that the array length is undefined.

The line I'm using to print the array length is:

```
console.log("sources array length = " + sources.length);
```

it's in a for loop:

```
        for (index=0;index < numImages ;index++){
        console.log(index);
        images[index] = new Image();
        images[index].src = sources[index];
        console.log("Adding " + sources[index]);
        callback(images[index]);
        console.log("sources array length = " + sources.length);
    }
```

As you can see, I have another console.log statement in the loop, to log each time the loop is run...

```
console.log(index);
```

This line prints the value of the variable index each time the loop is run, starting at 0, and increasing by 1 each time until the loops ends when it reaches the value equal to the variable 'numImages'.

But, for some reason, the line that should be printing the array length is displaying "sources array length = undefined" each time the loop runs, and not the actual length of the array.

Can anyone point out to me why this is? How can I make it display the length of the sources array each time the loop is run?

**Edit 13/02/2013 @ 15:10**

The sources array is defined in the same file, using the line:

```
var sources = {};
```

The reason I have not defined a set length for the array, is because I need its length to by dynamic. I have then added elements to the array using lines like this:

```
sources[0] = document.getElementById("building").src,
sources[1] = document.getElementById("chair").src,
sources[2] = document.getElementById("drink").src,
sources[3] = document.getElementById("food").src,
```

So what I want my console.log line to do, is tell me the length of the array as it currently is, i.e. how many elements have been added to it. As you can see in the first bit of code I had in my original post, I have a console.log which prints a message to the console every time an element is added to the sources array- they clearly are being added properly, as otherwise, they wouldn't be displayed on the canvas... so the array must have a length which is defined at the point that the images are drawn to the canvas, otherwise they wouldn't be in the array to be drawn.

Comment: How and where do you define your `sources` variable?

Comment: Where is `sources` defined?

Comment: I've added the code to show where `sources` is defined, and how it's used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But, for some reason, the line that should be printing the array length is displaying "sources array length = undefined" each time the loop runs, and not the actual length of the array.

...which tells us that `sources` doesn't have a `length` property, and thus is not an array. It's entirely possible to build something that *isn't* an array but which nevertheless has properties with names like `0`, `1`, etc. For instance:

```
var sources = {0: "zero", 1: "one", 2: "two"};
console.log(sources[0]); // "zero"
console.log(sources.length); // "undefined"
```

If you're getting `sources` by outputting some server-side information, it may well be being output in the form above (a plain object with numeric property names, which probably would be in quotes) rather than as an actual array, which would look like this:

```
var sources = ["zero", "one", "two"];
```

---

Re your edit

> The sources array is defined in the same file, using the line:
>
> ```
> var sources = {};
> ```
>
> The reason I have not defined a set length for the array, is because I need its length to by dynamic. I have then added elements to the array using lines like this:
>
> ```
> sources[0] = document.getElementById("building").src,
> sources[1] = document.getElementById("chair").src,
> sources[2] = document.getElementById("drink").src,
> sources[3] = document.getElementById("food").src,
> ```

That's not a problem, JavaScript arrays are dynamic (in fact, they're [not really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html) — or at least, the standard kind aren't, there are newer typed ones that actually are arrays). So just change

```
var sources = {};
```

to

```
var sources = [];
```

to make it actually an array. Then you can add to the array the way you are already doing it (that's absolutely fine) *or* you can use `sources.push(document.getElementById("chair").src);` and such instead.

Comment: I guess it is a plain object `{}` which has `length` as `undefined`.

Comment: I created it using the line `var sources = {};` which, as I understand, is how you create an empty array?

Comment: What's the difference between an empty array `{}` and a plain object `{}`? I didn't know there was a plain object one...

Comment: @someone2088: `{}` isn't an empty array, it's a blank object. Arrays are objects, but objects are not necessarily arrays. `[]` is an empty array. See also the updated answer (including the link).

Comment: Thanks T.J. Crowder- that's excellent- certainly helped clear up my understanding of arrays a bit anyway!